# Sed replace between and including 2 patterns

Tags: regex, sed, escaping, non-greedy

Hi guys I am doing the following

```
sed -i -e 's/[.*]//g'
```

I am trying to remove 2 known patterns and everything inbetween for each line.

From

```
[01]Hello
I am[abc]
[123abc]Chris
```

To

```
Hello
I am
Chris
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: Escape the `[]`s: `s/\[.*\]//g'`

Comment: Post it as answer @JamesBrown

Comment: Because of `g` I suggest `'s/\[[^[]*\]//g'`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following here, making `#` as `sed` separator for more clarity. In case you want to save output into Input_file itself use `sed -i` in code too.

```
sed 's#\[.*\]##g'  Input_file
```